# The number of $2\times n $ matrices in which each of {1,2,3.....2n} appears once

Tags: matrices

Show that the number of $2\times n $ matrices in which each of {1,2,3.....2n} appears once and and such that each row and column is increasing is equal to the $n^{th}$ Catalan number.

What i guess to  such a matrix consider a sequence $a_1, a_2,......a_{2n}$ where $a_i=1$ if i is the first row and -1 if i is the second row.

The first few Catalan numbers for n = 0, 1, 2, 3, … are 1, 1, 2, 5, 14, 42, 132, 429, 1430, 4862, …

for Catalan number:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

can any one help me for complete solution

Comment: what is the {1,2,3.....2n}??

Answer (score 1):

Your idea: "Consider  sequences $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{2n})$ where $a_i=1$ if $i$ goes into the first row, and $a_i=-1$ if $i$ goes into the second row" is fine. Given such a sequence you can immediately jot down the matrix by writing the $i$s with $a_i=1$ in increasing order in the first row, and then write the remaining $i$s in increasing order in the second row.

Since you can freely choose the $n$ numbers appearing in the first row there are ${2n\choose n}$ such sequences. This binomial coefficient is related to the Catalan numbers, but the official definition of the latter is $C_n:={1\over n+1}{2n\choose n}$.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a map, let's try to show that the map defines a bijection between your set of matrices and the set of sequences of $n$ $1$'s and $n$ $-1$'s such that the partial sums are always non-negative (whatever basic definition of Catalan numbers you have, and there are many, this set is likely easily seen to have size $c_n$, e.g., it is easy to pair such sequences with parenthesations).

The first step is to verify that the sequences generated by your map satisfy that property.  The second will be to construct an inverse map (making sure the inverse goes from acceptable sequences to acceptable matrices), and finally we verify that the inverse map actually is an inverse. To that end, call your map $f$.

It is clear that for a matrix $M$ from your set, $f(M)$ has $n$ $1$'s and $n$ $-1$'s. We must check that the partial sums of $f(M)$ are non-negative.  Let $b_1, b_2,\ldots, b_n$ be the entries in the second row of $M$.  Because the second row is increasing and the first column is increasing, $f(M)$ doesn't have any $-1$'s until we get to index $b_1$, at which point it will have at least one $+1$ at the index from the entry in $M$ above $b_1$.  Similarly, by the time we have two $-1$'s (which occurs at $b_2$), we will have at least two $+1$'s at the indices in the first two columns of the top row of $M$.  By induction, by the time our sequence has $k$ $-1$'s, it will already have at least $k$ $+1$'s coming from the indices in the first $k$ entries of the top row (which are all before $b_k$ because the columns are increasing).  Therefore, because we always have at least $k$ $+1$'s in the sequence before we reach our $k$th $-1$, the partial sums must all be non-negative.

Next, we define an inverse map, and then we show that it actually is an inverse.  To a sequence $(a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_{2n})$, we have $n$ indices where $a_i=1$, we take those in order, and make them the entries of the first row.  The entries of the second row are then the remaining indices in order.  By construction, both rows are increasing, and if the $k$th column was not increasing, then our $k$th $-1$ would have appeared before our $k$th $+1$, and we would have a partial sum that was negative.  Therefore, this map sends acceptable sequences to acceptable matrices.

Verifying that the two maps are actually inverses is left as an exercise for the interested reader. (Muahahahahahaha, being evil is fun.)